# Как создать несколько экземпляров «саморисующегося» компонента?

Tags: java, swing

Есть класс `Main`, где я создаю окно программы через `JFrame`. Затем я создаю два экземпляра класса Snow, но рисуется только один из них - второй, почему так? У них одинаковые координаты, или что? Еще у меня дурацкая реализация таймера, если подскажете, как исправить, буду благодарна.

```
public class Main {

    public static ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("src/li/domik.jpg");
    public static Image image = imageIcon.getImage();

    public static void creatWindow() throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setSize(1024, 768);
        jFrame.setLocation(500, 150);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);

        jFrame.add(new Snow(100, 100));//Казалось бы, создаю 2 экземпляра класса
        jFrame.add(new Snow(200, 200));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws InterruptedException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {
        creatWindow();
    }
}
```

И вот класс Snow:

```
public class Snow extends JComponent {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Timer timer;
    private boolean ingame = true;

    public Snow(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void timerRun() {
        ingame = false;
        timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (y < 700) {
                    y++;
                    repaint();
                } else {
                    x = new Random().nextInt(1000) * (1);
                    y = new Random().nextInt(200) * (-1);
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        }
    );
}

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRoundRect(x, y, 10, 10, 10, 10);
        if (ingame == true) {
            timerRun();
            timer.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Наталия, помочь мы можем, только к коду неплохо бы прилагать описание того, что именно вы хотите получить? Что именно вы хотите нарисовать и где?

Comment: В конечном счёте хотелось сделать картинку домика, и чтобы много снежинок падали вниз. А в данном коде - просто чтобы было несколько падающих снежинок чёрного цвета на белом фоне(экземпляры класса Snow),с разными координатами X и Y

Comment: Сейчас в примере не согласованы скобки в `timerRun` и используется необъявленная переменная `ingame1`. Исправьте ошибки чтобы код можно было бы скомпилировать без редактуры.

Comment: Исправила...благодарю за замечание)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Настройте абсолютное позиционирование для `JFrame`.

[`JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) по умолчанию использует `BorderLayout`. Это менеджер, который распределяет компоненты по своей логике (в данном случае два компонента на все окно, один поверх другого.

Для того, чтобы устанавливать компоненты в заданные координаты, сбросьте `Layout` по умолчанию:

```
Container pane = jFrame.getContentPane();
pane.setLayout(null);
```

Можете также почитать урок по абсолютному позиционированию в Swing: [Doing Without a Layout Manager (Absolute Positioning)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html). Вообще, было бы полезно пройти [всю тему по расположению компонентов](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

2. Задайте координаты и размеры для снежинок.

Сейчас класс `Snow` — большой компонент, который занимает все окно и внутри себя отрисовывает падающую снежинку. Чтобы каждый компонент вел себя как одна снежинка нужно ограничить размеры и изменить отрисовку.

При переходе на абсолютное позиционирование класс `Snow` не будет отрисовываться вовсе т.к. для него не задаются расположение и размеры.

Границы компонента можно задать с помощью [`setBounds`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)):

```
 //начальные значения в конструкторе
 ...
 this.y = y;
 //снежинка 10X10 в позиции (x;y)
 setBounds(x, y, 10, 10);

 //которые нужно изменять в таймере
 if(y<700) { 
      y++;
 } else { 
      x = new Random().nextInt(1000)*(1);
      y = new Random().nextInt(200)*(-1);
 }
 setBounds(x, y, 10, 10);
 repaint();
```

Код рисования тоже нужно будет изменить:

```
 //рисуем на весь компонент
 g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10);
```

Comment: Все замечания верны, правда в этом коде будут не снежинки, а падающая с неба черная железная руда)) Но это уже проблемы реализации кода того, кто задавал вопрос, а  ответу однозначно +1

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, теперь все работает)))